# Github does not show number of commits each day on starting page

Tags: github, commit, github-pages

I wonder why on GitHub I do not see the number of commits on starting page. I need to enter the Calculator repository to see that there are 40 commits.

Anybody knows how to fix it?

I was reading on GitHub documentation but I couldn't struggle with it and I was afraid of losing my repo.

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. What are you trying to fix? What do you expect to see? Can you send us a link to the page you're looking at?

Comment: I assume the colour of each square is indicative of the number of commits you have made, but I would not use this diagram to count commits. Go to each of your repo(s) to determine that. In other words, there is nothing to fix here - that illustration is working normally.